# KnockoutJS not finding attributes when new scope added

Tags: knockout.js, magento2

I've got a Magento2 project where i have a minicart that has attributes like qty, item_it etc.

```
<input data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           'data-item-qty': qty,
                           'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                           }, value: qty"
                           type="number"
                           size="4"
                           class="item-qty cart-item-qty qty-box-additions">
```

I have since added 2 buttons above and below that i want to add functionality to increase QTY, to do this i made a custom component :

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "qty_change": {
                        "component": "Magento_Catalog/js/view/product/view/qty_change",
                        "defaultQty": 1
                    }
                 }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I have now wrapped the input box in a data-bind="scope: 'qty_change'" so the input box now looks like this :

```
<div class="control" data-bind="scope: 'qty_change'">
                <div class="details-qty qty">
                    <label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Qty', attr: {
                           for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty'}"></label>

                           <button data-bind="click: decreaseQty">-</button>

                           <input data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           'data-item-qty': qty,
                           'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                           }, value: qty"
                           type="number"
                           size="4"
                           class="item-qty cart-item-qty qty-box-additions">
                           <button data-bind="click: increaseQty">+</button>

                    </button>
                     </div>
                </div>
```

Since doing this, i am getting

> Message: item_id is not defined

I understand it is because i have changed the scope to 'qty_change', but is there a way to keep it in the scope and just extend the current scope with my JS? This is my qty_change.js

```
//this file is attached to the + and - button in the minicart.
define([
    'ko',
    'uiComponent'
], function (ko, Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            //initialize parent Component
            this._super();
            this.qty = ko.observable(this.defaultQty);
        },
        decreaseQty: function() {
            var newQty = this.qty() - 1;
            if (newQty < 1) {
                newQty = 1;
            }
            this.qty(newQty);
        },
        increaseQty: function() {
            var newQty = this.qty() + 1;
            this.qty(newQty);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: This looks related: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120447/how-does-magento-2-apply-knockoutjs-bindings